# AngularJS $scope not accessible outside the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've written the following code to get the value from input fields and save it.
I defined a global variable and put the output in it to use in app.factory. the problem is "x" is only readable inside the "update function" and undefined anywhere outside it.
how can I solve this?

```js
var app = angular.module('bomApp', ['bomGraph']);

app.controller('bomController', ['$scope', 'appService', '$rootScope', function ($scope, appService, $rootScope) {
   
    var get = function () {
        appService.get().then(function (promise) {  

            $scope.graph = {
                
                options:  {
                    "hierarchicalLayout": {
                        "direction": "UD"
                        
                    },
                    "edges": {
                        "style":"arrow-center",
                        "color":"#c1c1c1"
                    },
                    "nodes": {
                        "shape":"oval",
                        "color":"#ccc"

                    }
                },
                
                data: {
                    nodes: promise.nodes,
                    edges: promise.edges
                }
            };
             
            
        });
        
    };
    
    $scope.newNode = {
        id: undefined,
        label: undefined,
        level: undefined,
        parent: undefined,
       
    };

    $scope.arrNode = {};
    $scope.update = function (nodes) {
        $scope.arrNode = angular.copy(nodes);
        $rootScope.x = angular.copy(nodes);
        
       
    };

   
    
    $scope.newEdge = {
        id: undefined,
        from: undefined, 
        to: undefined
       
    };
   
    $scope.arrEdge = {};
    $scope.updateE = function (edges) {
        $scope.arrEdge = angular.copy(edges);
        
    };
    
   
    get();
    

}]);



app.factory('appService', ['$q', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($q, $http, $rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.x);
    return {
        get: function (method, url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('data.json')
              .success(function (response) {
                  deferred.resolve(response);
                  
              })
            return deferred.promise;
           
        }, 
     
        
    };
    
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var x;` is local to the controller alone. It can't be accessed in the factory.

Mostly if you want to share data between `controllers` you will store it in `service`. It's a bad practice also to share declare global variables in the controller

In your case, actually a `closure` is being created and `x` is a `private` variable. It can be accessed only within the controller.

In case you want to access variable `x` in service, then use `$rootScope`

example:

```
app.controller('bomController', ['$scope', 'appService',  '$rootScope',function ($scope, appService,$rootScope) {

    $scope.update = function (nodes) {
       $scope.arrNode = angular.copy(nodes);
       $rootScope.x = angular.copy(nodes);
    };
});
```

In your service:

```
app.factory('appService', ['$q', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($q, $http, $rootScope) {
      // you will have access to $rootScope.x
});
```

Comment: Thank you..as I'm totally new to Angular could you make it a little bit more clear where and how to write it?

Comment: Updated my answer. please check

Comment: Thank you for your time, it's accessible but running console.log() returns the following errors: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:77)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.min.js:27)
    at angular.min.js:28
    at c (angular.min.js:26)
    at d (angular.min.js:26)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.min.js:27)
    at $get (angular.min.js:50)
    at angular.min.js:42
    at m (angular.min.js:6)
    at k (angular.min.js:42)

Comment: updated answer. forgot to include it within the [ ]. Now try the above code

Comment: So strange...again it's undefined anywhere outside the function.

Comment: Where are you trying to use it? Did you run $scope.update function before accessing it anywhere outside?

Comment: you are having a promise for fetching the data.json. The time taken to get it will take time. But the console.log in service will fire when the service is initialised itself.

Comment: and one more thing, no need to have `$rootScope.x;` at the beginning of the controller function.

Comment: I got it, so I guess If I use the $rootScope.x for a Post method to update the json it should work. you were a great help, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare x outside of the function:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wh5u3sf/5/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <button ng-click="fn()">{{x}} click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.x = "hello";

    $scope.fn = function () {
        $scope.x = "world";
    }  
})
```

Comment: again undefined outside the function.

Comment: @ShadiM. Seems like you solved your problem already. Added an example to show you what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global `$scope` variable instead, `$scope.x`;